# Simple spring data jpa transaction to small table on mysql database is hanging indefinitely

Tags: mysql, sql, spring-data-jpa

I have a spring data jpa query that reads a row from a mysql table with a pessimistic lock. In my environment, this table only contains one row so it should be pretty fast.

The spring data jpa function is named FindTopByIsCurrent(boolean iscurrent) which should just retrieve the only element of the table.

When the command runs, it hangs indefinitely. Checking the output of SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS

```
---TRANSACTION 170279307,

ACTIVE 3859 sec
2 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 11665, OS thread handle 140237095196416, query id 770252923 10.51.5.32 root
TABLE LOCK table `mydb`.`mytable` trx id 170279307 lock mode IS
RECORD LOCKS space id 722 page no 3 n bits 72 index PRIMARY of table `mydb`.`mytable` trx id 170279307 lock mode S
Record lock, heap no 2 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 34303030; asc 4000;;
 1: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 2: len 6; hex 0000000bf801; asc       ;;
 3: len 7; hex b2000001260110; asc     &  ;;
 4: len 1; hex 01; asc  ;;
```

This table is only for use by this one application and there are no other transactions in the list from show engine. The performance schema thread table doesn’t have a thread with id 11665. Additionally, when i log onto the db and run

`select * from mytable`

I immediately receive any information I need, so the table isn’t being locked in a way that prevents reads.

Here is the table (is_current is a true bit)

```
*************************** 
1. row 
***************************

version: 4000
local_index: 0

 is_current: 

1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Additionally, this is a random issue. In about 3/4 of cases this error does not appear. In 1/4 this appears in every transaction the service attempts. Further debugging has shown that the hang occurs in the middle of the query, the block occurs before we have the opportunity to commit

Comment: What queries are being run?  Are there multiple connections active at the same time?

Comment: @RickJames Only query is the "FindTopByIsCurrent" function which is spring data jpa's way of saying

"select * from mytable where is_current = true; "

The server has a lot of connections, about 300. I've set max_connections to 500 and verified this via the show variables. The specific table is only accessed by this one transaction, and the hang is preventing anything else from accessing the database so that's also only accessed by this one call

Comment: @Rick James Additionally this issue is intermittent

Comment: No `ORDER BY` or `LIMIT`?

Comment: @RickJames My mistake. "select * from mytable where is_current = true limit 1" I do not use an order by because the function will only be called to look for is_current=true and the way we add entries to the table there will never be more than one true. That said, in the current test case where I see a failure, there is only one entry in the table so both order and limit would be meaningless

Comment: Additionally, the query itself isn't the cause. For further debugging I added "select 1 from dual" just before my query and it hangs on that call as well.

Comment: Is the statement a transaction unto itself?  Or part of a larger transaction?

Comment: @RickJames Transaction unto itself

Comment: What is your JDBC connection url and settings? How are you getting a connection? Are you using a connection pool? Are you making changes to the connection once obtained? How often is the single row being updated? Are you committing the transaction after each update? What are your MySQL server settings, especially log and transaction related ones?

Comment: @Bohemian We are using a hikari connection pool. During the hang, the pool states it has 2 active connections out of the 10 available. The row is updated exactly once by adding the entry to it before the read query is run, it is never updated again.

Comment: The hang is occurring in the middle of the query, as a result we never reach the commit call. In terms of MySQL server settings, I'm going to need a lot more specifics than that. There's a lot of variables. Max connections is 500 but we utilize around 300ish when this failure occurs

Comment: Sounds like a deadlock. Is the transaction updating anything else, either explicitly or implicitly via a trigger?

Comment: @Bohemian the symptoms seem liked a deadlock, which is why I checked that first.

Comment: Firstly, I added “select 1 from dual” to the program to be run before the table read. This request hangs with the same symptoms. Secondly, the table in question is only accessed by the one program/thread. Thirdly, the access is a read. Fourthly, the output of SHOW ENGINE above shows only one shared lock and no other transactions, and the “recent deadlocks” section isn’t present

Comment: What is your MySQL version and how are you running it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently it is a deadlock, but it has nothing to do with SQL.

I was running another transaction in another thread. The transaction involved reading from a different table in a different database (same server). Additionally, both transactions I was running occurred in a PostConstruct method of their spring beans. I kind of tunnel visioned on SQL related causes and ignored the possibility that the unrelated read could cause an issue

These transactions apparently need to lock a specific SingletonSupplier and ConcurrentHashmap, and they each locked one of the two and deadlocked against each other.

```
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getSingletonFactoryBeanForTypeCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1006)
- waiting to lock <0x00000000c189bf40> (a java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:907)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isTypeMatch(AbstractBeanFactory.java:637)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:583)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:550)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:265)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1555)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1352)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory$DependencyObjectProvider.getObject(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1988)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.data.RepositoryMetricsAutoConfiguration$$Lambda$891/1598942787.get(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.util.function.SingletonSupplier.get(SingletonSupplier.java:97)
- locked <0x00000000c2ca1c40> (a org.springframework.util.function.SingletonSupplier)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.data.MetricsRepositoryMethodInvocationListener.lambda$afterInvocation$0(MetricsRepositoryMethodInvocationListener.java:87)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.data.MetricsRepositoryMethodInvocationListener$$Lambda$1121/652710755.accept(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.AutoTimer.apply(AutoTimer.java:109)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.data.MetricsRepositoryMethodInvocationListener.afterInvocation(MetricsRepositoryMethodInvocationListener.java:86)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryInvocationMulticaster$DefaultRepositoryInvocationMulticaster.notifyListeners(RepositoryInvocationMulticaster.java:76)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:148)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:159)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:145)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
```

Comment: I am running into this exact issue. How did you resolve it or RCA it?

Comment: @java_doctor_101 I removed one of the transactions from the PostConstruct. Probably should report this to the spring people though… If that isn’t an option, use a lock object I guess